# Firebase only allowing a certain number of records to be written

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am working on ticketing system, where I don't want to oversell. 
I have to insert the data in slots only if, it is **less than 'total_seats**' or  **'available_seats' > 0**

How to do this ?
 [image: Here's my Data Structure]

Comment: did you tried any code ? whats the error ?

Comment: Read the `Transaction` parts of the official document, it tells you how to avoid those conflict things.

Comment: @GastónSaillén
I tried this database rules by searching online for references
`"registrations":{
       "slot_1":{
           ".write": "root.child('star_night/slots/slot_1/available_seats').val() > 0"
         }
       }`